# How to use contains() function to check in strings the presence of predefined substrings and count() the strings that match?

Tags: xml, count, xslt-1.0, contains

I'm trying to check in strings the presence of predefined substrings and then want to count() the elements that match these formats.

My example follows:

```
<!-- xslt code snippet; this is what I did, but I don't know
     how to count() them, I'm getting something like 111 as output :|
-->
<xsl:for-each select="automobile">
    <xsl:if test="contains(name_and_class, 'J.TK') or
        contains(name_and_class, 'P.LO') or contains(name_and_class, 'M.GA')">
        <xsl:value-of select="name_and_class"/>
 <!-- how can I count() them here-->
 
 <!-- xml code snippet -->
<automobile>
<name_and_class>Mercedes B.OO</name_and_class>
</automobile>
<automobile>
<name_and_class>Hummer P.LO</name_and_class>
</automobile>
<automobile>
<name_and_class>Audi J.TK</name_and_class>
</automobile>
<automobile>
<name_and_class>Ferrari M.GA</name_and_class>
</automobile>
<automobile>
<name_and_class>Mercedes F.BQ</name_and_class>
</automobile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use predicate (expression in `[]`) to filter elements, for example assuming that we have the following well-formed XML as input :

```
<root>
    <automobile>
    <name_and_class>Mercedes B.OO</name_and_class>
    </automobile>
    <automobile>
    <name_and_class>Hummer P.LO</name_and_class>
    </automobile>
    <automobile>
    <name_and_class>Audi J.TK</name_and_class>
    </automobile>
    <automobile>
    <name_and_class>Ferrari M.GA</name_and_class>
    </automobile>
    <automobile>
    <name_and_class>Mercedes F.BQ</name_and_class>
    </automobile>
</root>
```

this template will output count of `name_and_class` elements that match the criteria without using `xsl:for-each` :

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(automobile[
        contains(name_and_class, 'J.TK') or
        contains(name_and_class, 'P.LO') or 
        contains(name_and_class, 'M.GA')
        ])"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform demo`](http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWn/1)</kbd>**

output :

```
3
```